# Error with Named Arguments when programming Odbc

Tags: sql, statistics, stata

I'm writing a Stata program that will, hopefully, simplify my queries to a database. I wrote a really simple program that uses the `SQL_Syntax' named argument to add SQL code; however, every time I run the program I receive the following error:

> The ODBC driver reported the following diagnostics
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '�'.
> SQLSTATE=42000

My code is written below:

```
capture program drop SQL_Stata

program define SQL_Stata
    version 14.2 
    args SQL_Syntax 

macro list

clear 
#delimit; 
odbc load, exec("
‘SQL_Syntax’
")
dsn("SQL Server");
#delimit cr

end
```

I initially used a positional argument, `0' but switched back to a named argument when this didnt work out

Also, the code in the program works with a real query:

```
clear 
#delimit; 
odbc load, exec("
SELECT * 
FROM TestDB.Cases_2023_6_12
")
dsn("SQL Server");
#delimit cr
```

Comment: I would first start by writing a working query, then replace ```exec("**your working query**")``` with a macro ```exec("`sql_query'")``` and once this works try to fit it into a function. Are you able to load data with a query that does not use a macro?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! Yes, the code works when I put the actual query in the quotes but not when it's used as a function

Let me add that to the code snippet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps worked for me (I deleted my personal information):

First, check that your connection is working it all

```
odbc load, exec("SELECT * FROM TABLENAME FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY") ///
    user(USERNAME) password(PASSWORD) dsn(SERVER) clear
```

Then check that this works too

```
clear
local query "SELECT * FROM TABLENAME FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY"
odbc load, exec(`"`query'"') user(USERNAME) password(PASSWORD) dsn(SERVER) clear
```

And finally you can use the program (and test it)

```
cap program drop SQL_query
program define SQL_query
    syntax , query(string)
    
    // delete user and password if your database does not require this
    odbc load, exec(`"`query'"') user(USERNAME) password(PASSWORD) dsn(SERVER) clear
end

SQL_query, query("select * from TABLENAME FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY")
```

---

Note that your username and password are hardcoded into the function which might be a security risk. A safer option is to use the username and password as parameter
**EDIT:** user and password are now optional arguments

```
program define Safer_SQL_query
    syntax , query(string) [User(string) Passowrd(string)]
    
    odbc load, exec(`"`query'"') user(`user') password(`password') dsn(SERVER) clear
end
```

You can save your credentials in a separate do-file with the content
`gobal credentials user(USERNAME) password(PASSWORD)`
and then load data with

```
//do this only once at the beginning
qui do your_credential_file.do

Safer_SQL_query, query("select * from TABLENAME FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY") $credentials
```

Comment: Maultasche, thank you so much for your help! Your code worked perfectly and helped me figure out my issue - I had an unnecessary set of quotation marks around the macro...quotation marks should truly be the first thing I check. Thanks again!